# How to remove duplicates in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

## Problem statement

Determine which pair of actors worked together most. Working together
is defined as appearing in the same movie. The output should have three
columns: actor 1, actor 2, and count. The output should be sorted by the count
in descending order. The solution to this question will require a self-join.

## Solution

I had the following query to solve it and the output. The output has duplicate values for actor 1 and actor 2, so I am wondering how can I remove these duplicates,

```
val df = movies.as("set").join(movies.as("anotherSet"), $"set.movie_title" === $"anotherSet.movie_title" && $"set.actor_name" =!= $"anotherSet.actor_name")
    .groupBy($"set.actor_name".as("actor 1"), $"anotherSet.actor_name".as("actor 2"))
    .count()
    .orderBy($"count".desc)

+-----------------+------------------+-----+
|          actor 1|           actor 2|count|
+-----------------+------------------+-----+
| Lynn, Sherry (I)|   McGowan, Mickie|   23|
|  McGowan, Mickie|  Lynn, Sherry (I)|   23|
| Lynn, Sherry (I)|   Bergen, Bob (I)|   19|
|  Bergen, Bob (I)|   McGowan, Mickie|   19|
|  McGowan, Mickie|   Bergen, Bob (I)|   19|
|  Bergen, Bob (I)|  Lynn, Sherry (I)|   19|
|  McGowan, Mickie|   Angel, Jack (I)|   17|
|  Angel, Jack (I)|   McGowan, Mickie|   17|
|  Angel, Jack (I)|  Lynn, Sherry (I)|   17|
| Lynn, Sherry (I)|   Angel, Jack (I)|   17|
|  McGowan, Mickie|       Rabson, Jan|   16|
| Lynn, Sherry (I)|       Rabson, Jan|   16|
|      Rabson, Jan|   McGowan, Mickie|   16|
|      Rabson, Jan|  Lynn, Sherry (I)|   16|
|Darling, Jennifer|   McGowan, Mickie|   15|
|  McGowan, Mickie| Darling, Jennifer|   15|
|  Bergen, Bob (I)|     Harnell, Jess|   14|
|Darling, Jennifer|  Lynn, Sherry (I)|   14|
|Sandler, Adam (I)|Schneider, Rob (I)|   14|
|    Harnell, Jess|   Bergen, Bob (I)|   14|
+-----------------+------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `least` and `greatest` to treat a pair like `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` the same for counting.

```
groupBy(least($"set.actor_name", $"anotherSet.actor_name").as("actor 1"),
        greatest($"set.actor_name", $"anotherSet.actor_name").as("actor 2")
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do by comparison and sorting at row level and then taking distinct records to count by Actor 1, Actor 2.

Something like this:

```
var df1 = m1.join(m2, m1("Movie") === m2("Movie") && m1("Actor") =!= m2("Actor")).
  select(m1("Movie"), 
         when(m1("Actor") < m2("Actor"),m1("Actor")).otherwise(m2("Actor")).as("Actor 1"), 
         when(m1("Actor") > m2("Actor"),m1("Actor")).otherwise(m2("Actor")).as("Actor 2")).
 distinct.groupBy("Actor 1","Actor 2").count
```